# functions not working in ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm doing a tutorial on youtube and I've gotten to a point where I need to loop through an array.  But when I try to run the function in an ejs template it doesn't work.  Anyone know what's causing this.

This is the function

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<%= users.foreach(function(){ %>
<li><%= user.first_name %></li>
<% }); %>
```

This is the array in my javascript file that I'm trying to loop through.

```
  var users = [
{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
  email:  'johndoe@gmail.com',
},
{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'Bob',
  last_name: 'Smith',
  email:  'bobsmith@gmail.com',
},
{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'Jill',
  last_name: 'Jackson',
  email:  'jjackson@gmail.com',
},
```

];

Comment: well you need `user` as the first argument to `function()`.

Answer (score 1):

Array method should be `forEach()` and you need to pass each element of the array as a argument to the callback function, so `function(user) {...}`

Complete code

```
<% var users = [{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
  email:  'johndoe@gmail.com',
},
{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'Bob',
  last_name: 'Smith',
  email:  'bobsmith@gmail.com',
},
{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'Jill',
  last_name: 'Jackson',
  email:  'jjackson@gmail.com',
}]; %>

<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
<li><%= user.first_name %></li>
<% });%>
```

Comment: @CodeMonkey no problem, you can close the question by accept the answer as the correct answer